# Retrieving a javascript processed Web page

Tags: javascript, download

What am I asking for is the ability to download a rendered / processed page via Google Chrome or Firefox I think.

For example, I don't want:

```
hendry@x201 ~$ w3m -dump http://hello.dabase.com
FAIL
```

I want:

```
$ $answer http://hello.dabase.com
Hello World
```

Comment: In other words, you want to process page with browser and retrieve final DOM tree. However, what about `alert()`, ajax requests, `setInterval()`/`setTimeout()`?

Comment: Er, it's not simple / general enough

Comment: What's the real application here? Looks like unix to me? I'm wondering why Javascript is involved

Comment: Older versions of [`links2`](http://links.twibright.com/) supported Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It is running WebKit without the visuals, but you get the same fast and native supports for JavaScript, HTML/DOM, CSS, SVG, Canvas, and many others.

Disclaimer: I started PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too early, but someone ported V8 to Go-lang, so now you could write your own client that makes use of this powerful combo:

http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/embedding-v8-javascript-engine-and-go/

Looks quite straightforward, doesn't require an ugly Java/Rhino stack and adopts the next big programming language.

Answer (score 1):

It looks similar to the problem http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jsdom:- https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

I'd build a node driver for it, but it's supposed to work with Rhino etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

I'd use the excellent [env.js](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js) library in conjunction with Rhino to simulate the browser environment as much as is technically possible. Once you've implemented some web spider bootstrap code you should be able to obtain the result you want above.

I'd be interested in other solutions to this though.